# Change in entropy of the Universe for charging/discharging a capacitor

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I just need to know what exactly happens when charging/discharging a capacitor. Is there any heat transfer between the capacitor and the surroundings? Is there a heat transfer between other parts of the surroundings (wires, the battery)?

Another thing I don't understand generally... How do we know if a process is reversible or irreversible? Should we take the third law of thermodynamics as a principle and calculate the change in the entropy of the Universe through the formula given for entropy? If so, how about a process like the free expansion of a gas in which there is no heat transfer but the entropy increases? What about an adiabatic process? Where is the start point for calculating the change in entropy of the Universe for charging/discharging a capacitor?

Answer (score 3):

All energy transfer in an (ideal linear) electrical circuit is a form of work. Its just moving charges in electromagnetic fields. Resistor transfer energy to something external to the circuit, and often this energy will end up dissipated as heat in the surroundings. Inductors and capacitors, however, simply store energy and then release it again. Work is done charging them up and work is done discharging them, but there is no heat transfer.

In thermodynamics a process is reversible if it can be reversed by an infinitesimal change in the conditions, in other words everything is at the same temperature, pressure, etc (give or take an infinitesimal difference so that something actually happens) If energy is conserved in our process them the sum of all the heat transferred between different parts of our system must be 0. If, for a reversible change, everything is at the same temperature and \begin{equation} \mathrm{d}S = \frac{\mathrm{d}Q_{rev}}{T}\end{equation} This implies that the total change in entropy must also be 0.

Answer (score -2):

For charging a capacitor, it is true that dQ/T is zero, but the entropy is ds=dQ/T + dW/T by using the fundamental equation dU=TdS-PdV. PdV is simply the work done. The battery does work to store that energy so S is not zero.

Comment: A capacitor doesn't do work because the charge doesn't move across the capacitor. You can only do electrical work by moving a charge across an electric field to a region of different voltage. Since the charge in the capacitor never changes its voltage (its potential), it never does work. This should be obvious because discharging a capacitor is reversible.

Comment: W=1/2(CV^2). Work is done to store the energy in the electric field.

Comment: You can Google this to see that it's true.

Comment: no, electrical work is not performed unless the charged particle moves from one potential to another one. In a capacitor the charges don't cross from one plate to another.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe more clear if I say work done by the battery.

Comment: I have to downvote you because you won't listen.

Comment: Maybe you're confused about the difference between work and energy. Work is energy transferred to a different form. But the capacitor doesn't transform energy in the way that a resistor does. It just stores energy and then releases it.

Comment: I misspoke. Work is done by the battery, not the capacitor, to charge the capacitor. There is an overall increase of entropy associated with that. I'm looking right at the textbook answer key telling me this. I calculated the change in entropy using the method described above. Energy is transferred to the capacitor from the battery, this is the work done by the battery.

Comment: I am not one to copy and paste sources, but I will if I have to.

Comment: Maybe you are confused, and think I'm talking about charging AND discharging.

Comment: I will edit it the original comment to make that clear, but other than that I'm done here. These comments are much too lengthy.

Comment: @JesseLyon From that equation, dS = dU/T + dw/T.

Comment: du=dq when temperature is constant.